# Signing all PS scripts that are about to expire

Tags: powershell

I'm making a PS script that will sign all my previously signed scripts. This is what I currently have but its not re-signing the scripts

```
$oldcert = ""
$cert = (Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\my\)

Get-ChildItem "\\serverpath\" -Recurse -Include *.ps1* |
    Select-Object -expand fullname |
    ForEach-Object { 
        $path = $_
        $currentcert =  Get-AuthenticodeSignature $path | select SignerCertificate 
            If ($currentcert -eq $oldcert ) { Set-AuthenticodeSignature $path $cert }
 
        }
```

Comment: I have a feeling, that it tells you  "'If' is not  recognized as a name of a cmdlet" etc, as you can't pipe into an `If` like that. Remove the pipe after `Get-AuthenticodeSignature $path` and put the cmdlet's return value instead into a variable.

Comment: As Manuel above mentions, you have a bug in your code, and it is likely throwing error messages. If you want more/better help, also provide any error messages you are receiving.

Comment: I removed the Pipe and it returns the status but it does not set the new one

Comment: @ManuelBatsching Any idea on why It's not setting the signature? there is no error code

Comment: Please update the code in your question to how you changed it. Removing the pipe before the IF is not enough. The return value of `Get-AuthenticodeSignature` needs to go to a variable, in order to use it in the next line instead of the `$_`. Also note that according to your logic the signing only happens if the signercertificate is equal to the value of `$oldcert`. Is it?

Comment: @ManuelBatsching Yes, I only want to sign if it is a specific cert thats about to expire. I updated the code for where im currently at

Comment: `| select SignerCertificate ` will create an object with exactly one property: "SignerCertificate". That will not fulfill the conditon `$currentcert -eq $oldcert` because `$oldcert` is presumably not an object but a string. You need to expand a property to get to it's value:  `| select -ExpandProperty SignerCertificate `